# Подскажите библиотеку для визуализации графов на географической карте или другие способы

Tags: python, карты, визуализация

Стоит задача визуализировать пассажиропотоки между различными аэропортами, учитывая их величину (т.е чем больше поток, тем толще должна быть линия) на реальной карте, к примеру РФ.

Если бы не нужна была реальная картографическая подложка, то идеально подходит библиотека `networkx`, проблем нет.

Но такого функционала у `networkx` я не нашел, зато нашел в `arcgis`, который в свою очередь не может работать с графами так как это делает `networkx`.

Собственно вопрос: подскажите или библиотеку, позволяющую импортировать граф на карту или же есть какой-нибудь другой способ справиться с этим, к примеру средствами `matplotlib` и `pandas`.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего  `django.contrib.gis.geoip2` + `PostgreSQL` для хранения.
есть недавно переведенная книга на эту тему: Эрик Вестра. "Разработка геоприложений на языке Python".
А веб интерфейс можно использовать и в интранете если что )

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестировать!

Comment: если понравится - можете пометить мой ответ "зеленой галкой" как правильный. Это такой вариант "спасибо" на этом сайте. ;-)

Comment: Помечу сразу, как репутация будет больше 15 баллов) Система не позволяет новичку отметки ставить)

Comment: да не может быть. Раз задали вопрос, то только вы можете пометить один из ответов на него как правильный.
Я имею ввиду не комментарий, а серую галочку под единичкой слева вверху ))) Впрочем - неважно.